# Test equality of two json objects with express js

Tags: json, express

I'm using expressjs and I'm trying to determine if two json objects are the same and if so I increase a previously defined variable. Here's my code. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
app.get('/comp', function(req, res){
var body = {

        complexes: [
            { "Réponse 1":req.query.rep1},
            { "Réponse 2":req.query.rep2},
            { "Réponse 3":req.query.rep3
            }]
    };

filePath = '/home/smath/'+req.query.id+'.json';

    console.log(filePath);

var score_comp = 0;

fs.readFile('/home/smath/reponses_comp.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i=0; i<jsondata.complexes.length; i++){
            if (body.complexes[i] == jsondata.complexes[i])
        {  score_comp++ }
    }
})
```

And here's a glimpse of the reponse_comp.json file

```
{"complexes":[
{"Réponse 1":"a."},
{"Réponse 2":"a."},
{"Réponse 3":"a."}]}
```

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare two arrays or two objects.  That will only tell you if they are the same exact object (which they aren't) so it will never see equality.  Instead, if it's an array or object, you have to compare the individual array elements or object properties to see if they contain the same content.  There are tons of other answers here and code snippets on the web for comparing two objects in Javascript.  You don't need to write your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that properties are expressed in the same order in two JSON strings.